# How to restore objects from amazon glacier to standard tier permanently in a s3 bucket using python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to restore some objects in a s3 bucket from glacier to standard tier permanently below is my code

```
def restoreObject(latest_object):
    #s3_resource=boto3.resource('s3')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
    for bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
        object_key=bucket_object.key  
        if(bucket_object.storage_class == "Glacier_Deep_Archive"):
            if object_key in latest_object:
                my_bucket.restore_object(Bucket="bucket_name",Key=object_key,RestoreRequest={'Days': 30,'Tier': 'Standard'})
```

But this restores the bundle for a particular time only (30 days in my case)
Is there a way to restore bundles permanently from Glacier_Deep_Archive to standard tier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **permanently change** the Storage Class of an object in Amazon S3, either:

- Write code to `CopyObject` with the same Key (overwriting itself) while specifying the new Storage Class, or
- [Transition objects using Amazon S3 Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html) to let S3 do it automatically

However, Lifecycle policies do **not** seem to support going from Glacier to Standard tiers.

Therefore, you would need to **copy the object to itself** to change the storage class:

```py
  copy_source = {'Bucket': 'bucket_name', 'Key': object_key}
  my_bucket.copy(copy_source, object_key, ExtraArgs = {'StorageClass': 'STANDARD','MetadataDirective': 'COPY'})
```

Here's a nice example: [aws s3 bucket change storage class by object size · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/dlinsley/7670b1e14c936182bd09e9114fde63d7)

Comment: it's worth mentioning that this only works if the objects are restored